# How to send SMS with more than 160 characters and enable the customer to receive as ONE SMS using GSMComm library

Tags: sms, concatenation, modem

I'm developing SMS system using C# and using GSMCOMM free API(http://www.scampers.org/steve/sms/libraries.htm) to send SMS.

As the system can only send SMS less than 160 characters, I cut the LONG SMS into two messages and send them out.

The problem is that the customer will receive two SMS, which is quite irritating. Is there any way to enable customer to receive them as one SMS?

Answer (score 2):

If using HTTP, you have to set the MLC to 2.

Message length control: determines system behavior when the message length exceeds limits set by the mobile operator.

0 – Reject the MT if message text > maximum allowed for the target operator.
1 – Truncate the MT if message text > maximum allowed for the target operator.
2 – Automatically create multiple MTs dividing the message text at the point(s) where message text length = maximum allowed for the target operator.